# How to enable cloud providers for Déjà Dup on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10, backup, ubuntu-gnome, deja-dup

I'm using `deja-dup 36.3` on Ubuntu 17.10. trying to setup backup with deja-dup. It seems it supports lots of options but they are hidden:

[image]

For restore they are not hidden:
[image]

Digging deeper, I found this [commit](https://git.launchpad.net/deja-dup/commit/?id=6489179a5350473dd293ac6c8bc65c929d68e177) message from the [sole maintainer](https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+question/403967#1), saying it's being change so it's hidden by default but can be restored using `gsetttings`.

Why would someone hide all the good, supported, backup options?
I couldn't find the documentation saying how to do that. How does one change those `gsetttings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's hidden for "user convenience" and commercial reasons - trying to promote a particular vendor.

you can Install a tool called [dconf](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf) that lets us visually search for deja.
the key parameter we need to change is `backend` by default it's `goa` which only allows few cloud providers.
If you want to enable others-  change `s3` or `gcs` accordingly.
[image]

or using the command lines tool `gsettings`:
to check your current value use: 
`gsettings get "org.gnome.DejaDup" "backend"`

To change it use the `set`. for instance, 
`gsettings set "org.gnome.DejaDup" "backend" "gcs"`